# Return result after closing window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get value after window dialog is closed:

```
public partial class MyDialogWindow: Window
{
    public string selectedItem = "";
    public MyDialogWindow(string selectedItem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    ...
}


// To call dialog
string result = "";
MyDialogWindow dialog = new MyDialogWindow(result);
if (form.ShowDialog().Value)
{
   string res = result;
}
```

But 'result' always is empty. In winforms I can get this result, but in WPF not. So How to return result from window, after it is closed?

Comment: did you tried setting DialogResult..

Comment: @Vano Maisuradze - Why exactly are you doing a boolean check on the value of ShowDialog result? The boolean value of the current statement will always true.  The reason result is empty is because the DialogResult value has not been set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings don't work like that in C# - they are immutable.

You could get this to work using the `ref` keyword as other people have suggested, however this will only work if you set `SelectedItem` in the constructor, which is a bit unlikely!

The normal way of doing this is to have your dialog expose a property on your dialog:

```
public partial class MyDialogWindow: Window
{
    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get;
        set;
    {

    // etc...
}

MyDialogWindow dialog = new MyDialogWindow(result);
if (form.ShowDialog().Value)
{
   string res = dialog.SelectedItem;
}
```

This is the way that other dialogs (such as the open / save file dialogs) work.

Comment: Yes I know this way but is it a recommended way? I mean using class variable after ShowDialog(). Is it always guaranteed that dialog will not be null?

Comment: @Vano Yes this is the recommended way - `dialog` is a local variable and so in this instance there is no chance of it being null without a line of code that sets it to be `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an Example Window I just write:

```
public partial class ActionDialog : Window
{

    public ActionDialog(string msg)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MsgTbx.Text = msg;
    }

    //Record the user's click result
    public bool ClickResult = false;

    //In Other place need to use this Dialog just Call this Method
    public static bool EnsureExecute(string msg)
    {
        ActionDialog dialogAc = new ActionDialog(msg);
        //this line will run through only when dialogAc is closed
        dialogAc.ShowDialog(); 
        //the magic is the property ClickResult of dialogAc
        //can be accessed even when it's closed
        return dialogAc.ClickResult;
    }

    //add this method to your custom OK Button's click event        
    private void Execute_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClickResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }

    //add this method to your custom Cancel Button click event       
    private void Cancel_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClickResult = false;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And the code when calling the Dialog:

```
//simply one line can get the user's Button Click Result
bool isExecute = ActionDialog.EnsureExecute(msg);
```

Reference to

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5cae559-ff8c-4cd8-9c76-4e5821c9aefb/wpf-window-return-value?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1):

Add public property to the `MyDialogWindow` class and then just access it after the ShowDialog() was returned.

```
   class MyDialogWindow
   {
       public string UserEnteredData { get; set; }
   }


   if (form.ShowDialog().Value) 
   {    
      string res = dialog.UserEnteredData; 
   }
```